# Match word outside of specific sentence

Tags: regex, pcre

I was wondering if it's possible to match a word outside of a sentence.

This is the regex I have so far:

```
/(exchange|occasion|second hand)/im
```

Now I only want to match these words outside of this sentence:

> Shown prices, for exchange of ocassions are only for indication.

But I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Something like `/Shown prices, for exchange of ocassions are only for indication\.|(exchange|occasion|second hand)/i`. Only collect the Group 1 values.

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: PCRE regex @anubhava

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to match and skip anything](http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail) on LHS of an alternation like this:

```
/Shown prices, for exchange of ocassions are only for indication\.(*SKIP)(*F)|\b(exchange|occasion|second hand)\b/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JB01wT/1)

Comment: Thanks! This was the fix, I will accept your answer in 6 minutes.